# Stargazer with result from plm::pgmm() gives 'Error: Unrecognized object type.'

Tags: r, regression, stargazer, plm, gmm

Although `stargazer`is said to work with objects created by `plm::pgmm()` (see here) I get the error `Error: Unrecognized object type` when running the following code:

```
require(pder)
require(plm)
require(stargazer)

data("DemocracyIncome", package = "pder")

abond_2step <- plm::pgmm(
  formula = democracy ~ lag(democracy) + lag(income) | lag(democracy, 2:99) | lag(income, 2),
  data = DemocracyIncome, subset = sample==1, index = c("country", "year"),
  model = "twostep", effect = "twoways")

stargazer::stargazer(abond_2step) # yields 'Error: Unrecognized object type'
```

Am I doing something wrong or does `stargazer` not support objects created by `plm::pgmm()` any more? The relevant specification of my session are as follows:

- `R`: `4.0.4` (Mac)
- `plm`: `2.4-1`
- `pder`: `1.0-1`
- `stargazer`: `5.2.2`

Thanks a lot for your help!

*Edit: I figured out that when removing the explicit `plm::` befor `pgmm` the code works, yet I have no idea why:*

```
abond_2step_alt <- pgmm( # removed plm::
  formula = democracy ~ lag(democracy) + lag(income) | lag(democracy, 2:99) | lag(income, 2),
  data = DemocracyIncome, subset = sample==1, index = c("country", "year"),
  model = "twostep", effect = "twoways")

stargazer::stargazer(abond_2step_alt) # This works!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer**

The package does string matching to `abond_2step$call[1]`. In your case, that would be `plm::pgmm()`. The package is hardcoded to look for `pgmm()`, and thus doesn't properly set it.

**Another example of code that doesn't work**

```r
stargazer(stats::lm(Sepal.Length ~ ., iris))
```

**Rationale**

`stargazer` is written quite unconventionally. It has a lot of function definition INSIDE `stargazer::stargazer`, making it harder to find what actually happens.

At some point, a function named `.get.model.name` is called, which in turn calls `.model.identify`, which looks like this:

```r
.model.identify <-
  function(object.name) {
    
    if (class(object.name)[1]=="NULL") {   #### !!!!! continue this
      return("NULL")
    }
    
    if (class(object.name)[1]=="Arima") {
      return("Arima")
    }
    
    if (class(object.name)[1]=="fGARCH") {
      return("fGARCH")
    }
    
    if (class(object.name)[1]=="censReg") {
      return("censReg")
    }
    
    if (class(object.name)[1]=="ergm") {
      return("ergm")
    }
.........
```

The code that we care about:

```r
else if (object.name$call[1]=="pgmm()") {
   return("pgmm")
}
```

That's also where the problem is: `abond_2step$call[1]` returns `plm::pgmm()`. This is also exactly why your alternative call does work: `abond_2step_alt$call[1]` returns `pgmm()`.